# Loopback auto relation include filter not working

Tags: mongodb, relationship, loopbackjs

I have a model called category which can have multiple sub categories and belongs to one category, so, it's a auto related model. So I inserted a few in my database (I am using MongoDB) and I want to retrieve all my categories that doesn't belong to any one and include all it's sub categories, so the url is:

```
http://localhost:300/api/categories?filter={"where": {"category":  {"exists": false}}, "include": [{"categories": ["categories"]}]}
```

And what should return is this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    nome: "Elétrica",
    categories: [
      {
        _id: 2,
        nome: "Tomada",
        categories: [
          {
            _id: 3,
            nome: "Trocar Tomada"
          },
          {
            _id: 4,
            nome: "Tomada em Curto Circuito"
          },
          {
            _id: 5,
            nome: "Outros"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But it's returning this:

```
[
  {
    "nome": "Elétrica",
    "id": "5b7c6e2dcaaa163984a6ee76",
    "categorias": []
  }
]
```

And in my model.json, the relation is set like this:

```
"relations": {
    "categories": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "category",
      "foreignKey": "category"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "category",
      "foreignKey": "category"
    }
  }
```

One thing to mention, is that if I try the inverse query, so query all my categories which belongs to other category and include that category, it works.

Maybe this isn't a loopback issue or my url it's wrong, maybe the problem is that I actually have to store all the sub categories in the top category on Mongo, but I am not sure about that, so if anyone can help me if this..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to work by deleting the `belongsTo` relation in my model.